# How to recover master branch on the repo?

Tags: gitlab

Master branch is not exist in the remote repository: (it was there as well in the past)

[image]

But it still exists in the local:

[image]

And when I want to push it on the remote repository, it throws error:

[image]

Any idea how can I make the master branch on the remote repo? When I want to create it as a new branch through the gitlab interface, it says "master" is not an allowed name.

Comment: No pictures of text, please.

Comment: @matt You mean I have to copy paste the error massage instead of screenshot?

Comment: *"When I want to create it as a new branch through the gitlab interface, it says "master" is not an allowed name."* - this isnt git issue, [ask gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/support/), really. gitlab simply refuses your `master` branch push, and unfortunately political correctness is the sole reason.

Comment: "You mean I have to copy paste the error massage instead of screenshot?" Yes.

Comment: Yes, copy-paste ("copypasta" as many call it) is preferred: machine-readable text can be presented to more users more easily, e.g., those who are sight-impaired can have their computer read the text to them. See also [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Change your branch name from `master` to `main`.

If you are still having issues after the branch rename, simply rename your local git folder, and clone a fresh copy.

https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/03/10/new-git-default-branch-name/

Comment: this is a reasonable solution. though if the remote `master` contains the latest stuff then op is out of luck.